# Connecting to Azure Service Fabric cluster from Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to connect to my Azure Service Fabric cluster from a new Azure virtual machine I just set up. But when I use the Connect-ServiceFabricCluster cmdlet is get the following error message:

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : An error occurred during this operation.  Please check the trace logs for more details.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], FabricException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster
```

The command I am using in powershell is (values are obfuscated):

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint {ENDPOINT ADDRESS} -FindType FindByThumbprint -FindValue {THUMBPRINT} -X509Credential -ServerCertThumbprint {THUMBPRINT} -StoreLocation CurrentUser -StoreName My
```

When I use the exact same command on my development PC it is working just fine. Any suggestions on what is going wrong and how I might debug this is welcome!

Comment: Do you have your client certificate installed on the VM at the location indicated in the parameters?

Comment: @MattThalman That's it. Thanks! If you can add it as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure that you have your client certificate installed on the VM at the location indicated in the parameters to the Connect-ServiceFabricCluster cmdlet.